# How to show results in textboxes in php

Tags: php

I have this piece of code and I want to show result in the third input box not in the input box and hole page  and i want to know if i can a $_GET['$vairbles'] whiten  functions 
 NOTE : I’m beginner in php programming

Here is my code :

```
<?php

$email = "mail@somedomain.com";
if (isset($_GET['txt1']) and isset($_GET['txt2'])) if (!empty($_GET['txt1']) and!empty($_GET['txt2'])) {
    $tex1 = $_GET['txt1'];
    $tex2 = $_GET['txt2'];
    echo "They are all filled.<br>";
} else {
    echo "Please fill in first and second Fields";
}

shwor();

Function shwor() {
    global $email;
    global $tex1;
    global $tex2;
    $len1 = strlen($tex1);
    $len2 = strlen($tex2);
    if ($len1 and $len2 > 0) if ($tex1 == $tex2) echo "matched ";
    else echo "Does not match";
}
?>


<form action:"email.php" method="GET">
    <input 1 type="text" name="txt1"><br><br>
    <input 2 type="text" name="txt2"><br><br>
    <input 3 type="text" name="Result" value = "<?php shwor();?>"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Check matches"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are there `1`, `2` and `3` in your `input`s? Your code could do with some tidying  up

Comment: return "matched" return "Does not match" <?php echo shwor(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

everything works, just misspelled in this line:

```
<form action:"email.php" method="GET">
```

should be:

```
<form action="email.php" method="GET">
```

..and remember to name your file email.php that the data will be sent to the file itself ;-)